# How to change form color when it is in read mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a about me in form where I edit and save about me. The form color in read mode is in grey color, I want the color to be changed to white. how is it possible.

Snapshot is included for reference

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-10 aboutme">
  <h3>About Me</h3> 
  <div class="well row col-lg-12  "><!--Personal Info Col-->    
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="aboutme" ng-model="aboutme" 
              placeholder="Write about yourself" rows="10" ng-disabled ="!pEditMode"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```css
.form-control:disabled {background-color: #fff;}
```

For specificity and correctness, add an `id` or `class`:

```css
.aboutme .form-control:disabled {background-color: #fff;}
```